# Vertical space between caption and main text

Tags: spacing, floats, captions, floatrow, chemstyle

I am trying to adjust the vertical space between my captions and the main body of text below it. It is likely to be packages interfering with each other, but I am not sure which.

Herbert suggested including these commands into my preamble, and I have removed the caption package completely as it seems to be superseded by the `floatrow` package included with `chemstyle`.

```
 \captionsetup{
      justification=centering,
      singlelinecheck=false,
      font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space}
    \floatsetup{captionskip=6pt}
    \renewcommand\FBbskip{20pt}
```

But it seems as though `\FBbskip` is only having an effect on the first image float. I have updatd the MWE below so that this is clear, using `\FBbskip` at 20pt so you can clearly see the difference in vertical space between the two schemes.

Also. I am still unclear what these settings do:

```
\captionsetup{skip=5cm}
\addtolength\belowcaptionskip{20.0cm}
\addtolength\abovecaptionskip{20.0cm}
```

Commenting them out doesn't seem to have an effect, and setting them to extreme values doesn't seem to do anything either? Should I just remove them?

MWE using Herbert's solution, hopefully you can see the difference in vertical space surrounding the two schemes?

```
 \documentclass[11 pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}  
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans} 
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=.75in, bottom=.5in, includeheadfoot,   headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{achemso}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{times,mathptmx}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{balance} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[toc, page, header]{appendix} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[plain]{fancyref} 

 \captionsetup{
  justification=centering,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space}
\floatsetup{captionskip=6pt}
\renewcommand\FBbskip{20pt}

\linespread{1.8} %1.5 line spacing

\parindent=0pt 
\parskip=8pt 

\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\sffamily}{\small}
\renewcommand{\captionlabelfont}{\bf}
\renewcommand\thescheme{\arabic{scheme}}
\counterwithout{scheme}{chapter}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\captionsetup{skip=5cm}
\addtolength\belowcaptionskip{20.0cm}
\addtolength\abovecaptionskip{20.0cm}
\onehalfspace


\chapter[Introduction]{Introduction}
\chaptermark{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction} % label for referring to chapter in other parts of the thesis
\section[Importance]{Importance}\label{C1:Intro}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text     Text Text Text 

\begin{scheme}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{cat}
\caption{}
\label{scheme}
\end{scheme}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text     Text Text Text Text Text 
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text     Text Text Text 

\begin{scheme}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{dog}
\caption{}
\label{scheme}
\end{scheme}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text     Text Text Text Text Text 

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Package `chemscheme` loads itself package `floatrow` which controls the space above/below the caption with own settings:

```
\floatsetup{captionskip=10pt}%% space between figure and caption
\renewcommand\FBaskip{20pt}% space before float
\renewcommand\FBbskip{20pt}% space after float
```

You are looking for the latter. 
However, in your example the font setting is a bit weird. You load several font packages which overwrites each preceding one. Here an example with a correct font setting for bera:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bera}  
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans} 
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, includeheadfoot,    headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\captionsetup{
  justification=centering,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space}
\floatsetup{captionskip=1cm}
\renewcommand\FBbskip{20pt}


\parindent=0pt 
\parskip=8pt 

\renewcommand\thescheme{\arabic{scheme}}
\counterwithout{scheme}{chapter}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\captionsetup{skip=1cm}
\addtolength\belowcaptionskip{2cm}
\addtolength\abovecaptionskip{2cm}

\onehalfspace
\chapter[Introduction]{Introduction}
\chaptermark{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction} % label for referring to chapter in other parts of the thesis
\section[Importance]{Importance}\label{C1:Intro}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text     Text Text Text 

\begin{scheme}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{cat}
\caption{foo bar baz}
\label{scheme}
\end{scheme}

How I adjust the space between this text and the caption above??Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Herbert, this seems to fix the issue for the example I gave you, but when I put this into my actual document - changing the FBbskip doesn't seem to do anything (I tried setting it to 10cm to see if anything would happen). As before, I know this is probably because I am using packages and settings from someone else's document and I'm not completely sure of how each of these settings affect each other. I will keep playing with it to see if I can work it out. What do the \captionsetup{skip=1cm}, addtolength\belowcaptionskip{2cm} etc do in the example you posted?

Comment: Ok, so FBskip does seem to be changing the vertical space around the figure on my title page. Would my other schemes be ignoring this command because they are in a separate document (put in place via the \input{location} command?

Comment: Copying the \renewcommand{FBbskip=5cm} into my chapter 1 document, does alter the spacing around the first figure, but all of the others are left unchanged. Is there a way to set this option in the  preamble so that all figures will be adjusted?

Comment: put that option into preamble right before `\begin{documentclass}`

Comment: Do you mean just before \begin{document}? It only changes the next immediate figure (in this example scheme 1), not any of the other figures in the document. If there is more than one scheme the vertical space between the caption of scheme 1 and the following text is different to that between the caption for later schemes/figures and the text after them.

Comment: Then one of your environments resets that option. I need a _complete_ example which shows this behaviour.

Comment: The example I gave does show this behaviour when a second scheme is added. I have attached another example with this scheme included - with the FBbskip set to 20pt so you can clearly see the different spacings.